# Page not refreshed when clicked delete button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a page running at "http://localhost:4200/assignmentForAudit" and the UI looks like [image]

When i click delete button then the data gets deleted but the page is not refreshed. I tried to put  `this.router.navigate(['/assignmentForAudit']);` after delete operation but it is not refreshing the page.How can i achieve this refresh method so that the data gets removed?

method to delete in component.ts

```
onDelete(nas:any){
   this.assignmentAudit.id=nas.assignmentAudit[0].id;
   console.log(this.assignmentAudit.id);
  if(window.confirm('Are sure you want to delete this item ?')){
     this.assignmentAuditService.deleteGroupFromSelection(this.assignmentAudit.id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => console.log(error));
   }
    this.router.navigate(['/assignmentForAudit']);

}
```

assignment-audit.service.ts class method to call the api operation

```
deleteGroupFromSelection(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

Delete operation is working fine but the problem is the page is not refreshing.

Comment: `window.location.reload();` should work but it does complete page refresh, i suggest rather reloading just remove from the grid on successful delete.

Comment: After you deleted item on the server side, you need to query the list of items again. After you got the list just reassign it to appropriate component's property. Otherwise Angular has no idea that something changed.

Comment: Here is the article which might help you https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's not recommended at all as a best practice when you using angular you can simple emit `data list` after every `delete` with that you update the data visually too but if you want such behavior.

**First Case** by reload the whole page you can do so after every `delete`

```
window.location.reload();
```

**Second Case** if you need just to reload the component you can work around that and achieve it by a hack (just to trick the `component` you *navigate* away and *navigate* again to it)

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/DummyComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent you want to reload']));
```

`/DummyComponent` could be a empty component you just gonna use it to trick the actual component you need to refresh/reload

Comment: But it's not good practice to load whole page. :( . just want reload  component

Comment: i just update the answer that should work with you 'second case'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reload the page, call the http method which is used to populate the entries again on success of the delete http call.

```
     this.assignmentAuditService.deleteGroupFromSelection(this.assignmentAudit.id)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
this.entries = this.http.get() // something like this. here this.entries refers to data that is used to populate html.
              console.log(data);
            },
            error => console.log(error));
       }
```

You can also use a BehaviorSubject to emit a value, listening to it, you can decide on calling `this.entries = this.http.get()` again.

Comment: i need to reload the same page "/assignmentAudit" then how can i fit it in this.http.get() ?

Comment: Since this is SPA, we must avoid reload the page and  do the data reload/refresh as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the 'onSameUrlNavigation' option in Angular routes.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})
```

Comment: it says that it is not assinable to any[]

Answer (score 0):

Can your show how to binding array of object to template ? I thinks you just remove item from array then template it will update data too.

something like this:

```
this.nas.assignmentAudit = this.nas.assignmentAudit.filter(a => a.id !== this.assignmentAudit.id);
```